# Retrieve an entity by entity id

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In Datastore View, I can see

```
Edit Entity: SaleRecord
Decoded entity key: SaleRecord: id=4506503696351232

Entity key: ahJzfmF1dG90d2VldG1hY2hpbmVyFwsSClNhbGVSZWNvcmQYgICAwMLUgAgM
```

How can I retrieve that entity if I only know the key id (4506503696351232). 
(I am using Python)

I tried:

```
s= SaleRecord.get('4506503696351232')
```

but it returned errors

Comment: Please add the java or python tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

k = db.Key('ahJzfmF1dG90d2VldG1hY2hpbmVyFwsSClNhbGVSZWNvcmQYgICAwMLUgAgM')
s = db.get(k)
```

You can also create the key using the id, like this:

```
k = db.Key.from_path('SaleRecord', 4506503696351232)
```

Check the documentation for [`get`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#get) and [`Key`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass) for more information.

Comment: I only know the key id (4506503696351232), so that I cant use k = db.Key('ahJzfmF1dG90d2VldG1hY2hpbmVyFwsSClNhbGVSZWNvcmQYgICAwMLUgAgM')
s = db.get(k)

Comment: Suppose I dont know 'ahJzfmF1dG90d2VldG1hY2hpbmVyFwsSClNhbGVSZWNvcmQYgICAwMLUgAgM', how can I  retrieve the entity?

Comment: @John you should be able to do it like I wrote in the answer, e.g. `k = db.Key.from_path(SaleRecord, 4506503696351232)`.

Comment: thanks. But I got this error: File "/base/data/home/apps/s~autotweetmachine/4.382136699578691932/myapp/views.py", line 6988, in order
k = db.Key.from_path(SaleRecord, 4506503696351232)

File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 512, in from_path
(i + 1, kind, typename(kind)))

BadArgumentError: Expected a string kind as argument 1; received (a PropertiedClass).

Comment: @John, sorry, I missed the quotes around the kind name. I have updated the answer to: `k = db.Key.from_path('SaleRecord', 4506503696351232)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the  entity by id as shown below

```
sales_record = SaleRecord.get_by_id(id)
```